Smallest eigenvalue of certain PD matrix decreases under sparse perturbation
Let $\omega_1<\dots<\omega_n\in\mathbb{R}$. Then, define $G\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ such that $G_{k\ell}=\frac{1}{1-i(\omega_\ell-\omega_k)}$. For example, if $n=3$ we obtain $$ G=\begin{bmatrix}1 & \frac{1}{1-i(\omega_2-\omega_1)} & \frac{1}{1-i(\omega_3-\omega_1)}\\
 \frac{1}{1+i(\omega_2-\omega_1)} & 1 & \frac{1}{1-i(\omega_3-\omega_2)}\\ \frac{1}{1+i(\omega_3-\omega_1)} & \frac{1}{1+i(\omega_3-\omega_2)} & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$
One can show that $G$ is positive definite. Now, let $\varepsilon<\omega_2-\omega_1$ and define $G_{\varepsilon}\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ just as $G$ but replacing $\omega_1$ by $\omega_1+\varepsilon$.
I want to prove
$$\lambda_{\text{min}}(G_\varepsilon)\leq\lambda_{\text{min}}(G)$$
This is very easy to show in the $2\times 2$ case, as in that case we have a closed form formula for the least eigenvalue. Any comments on how could I prove it for the general $n\times n$ case? My thoughts to tackle the problem have been the following:
$\textit{1) Naive approach (failed)}$: it would suffice to show $G-G_\varepsilon\succeq 0$ and then conclude by Weyl's inequality. However,  $G-G_\varepsilon\not\succeq 0$. This is because $\textrm{Tr}(G-G_\varepsilon)=0$, which implies $0=\sum_{k=1}^n\lambda_k(G-G_\varepsilon)$ and then that $G-G_\varepsilon$ has at least one negative eigenvalue (considering that it is Hermitian and non-zero).
$\textit{2) Variational approach (unclear)}$: let $h:\mathbb{R}_+\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $$
h(\varepsilon)=\lambda_{\textrm{min}}(G_\varepsilon).
$$
By Weyl's inequality, $h$ is concave. Furthermore, the superdifferential of $h$ at $0$ can be characterized as
$$
\partial h(0)=\{v^*G'v\,|\,v\in\mathbb{C}^n.\, Gv=\lambda_\textrm{min}(G)v,\, \|v\|=1\}\quad\text{
where}\quad
G'=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\frac{G_\varepsilon-G}{\varepsilon}
$$
Then, if $v^*G'v\leq 0$ for some eigenvector $v$ associated to the smallest eigenvalue of $G$ we would have
$$
\lambda_{\text{min}}(G_\varepsilon)=h(\varepsilon)\leq h(0)+\langle v^*G'v,\epsilon \rangle\leq h(0)=\lambda_{\text{min}}(G)
$$
However, similarly as before, $\textrm{Tr}(G')=0$, and then $G'$ is not negative semi-definite. Then, for me its unclear how to prove that $v^*G'v\leq 0$ for some eigenvector $v$ associated to the smallest eigenvalue of $G$.
$\textit{Note}$: $G'$ has a structured form:
$$
G'=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & x^*\\
x & 0
\end{bmatrix}\quad\text{where}\quad x\in\mathbb{C}^{n-1}.\ x_k=\frac{-1}{(1+i(\omega_{k+1}-\omega_1))^2}
$$
Then, $\text{rank}(G')=2$, its non-zero eigenvalues are $\lambda_1=\|x\|_2$ and $\lambda_2=-\|x\|_2$, and they are associated to the eigenvectors
$$
u_1=\begin{bmatrix}
\|x\|\\ x
\end{bmatrix}\quad\text{and}\quad 
u_2=\begin{bmatrix}
-\|x\|\\ x
\end{bmatrix}
$$
respectively.

I don't think one can make much progress here without some information on what the eigenvector looks like (this also seems to be the gist of your comments).

I agree. Any comments on how to obtain meaningful information about the eigenvector associated to the least eigenvalue of G would be greatly appreciated.
